# (FLUTTER) Duda que tengo en flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Buenas noches compañeros,

Quería consultarles como ustedes consumirían una API con Patron Bloc?, ya que ando medio en una con eso, se me complica muchísimo el patron bloc.

Agradeceria respuestas, muchas gracias!

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones, y/o muy amplias, terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

utiliza la libreria http o dio para consumir una API
pero ten en cuenta que el patron bloc es una forma de manipular información,
en este sentido te recomiendo que primero consumas la API y posterior a ello manipules la información con Bloc o como a ti te parezca.
podrias hacer el consumo de una API dentro de un evento

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).